# Flushing entity A and B, when B's primary key is also A's? In JPA & Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have the following entities A and B

```
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "aId")
  private long aId;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private B b;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class B {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "bId")
/**
*
* This is the same id as A.
*/
  private long bId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
  private A a;
```

How I am flushing entity A and B

```
A aEntity = new A();
B bEntity = new B();
aEntity.setbEntity(bEntity);

this.entityManager.persist(A);
this.entityManager.persist(B);
this.entityManager.flush();
```

I am trying to save both these entities in a transaction and I am having issues where B's id is not getting hydrated down by A's id.

Comment: are'nt you missing a `@OneToOne` anotation on field `a` in class `B`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding that into my question. But it should be there. I've also tried adding @Id annotation to B's A and have also failed

Answer (score 0):

On `A.b` you have a `mappedBy="a"`, that means that `B.a` is the "owner" of the relation.
So you should set `B.a` instead of `A.b` to persist the relation:

```
B bEntity = new B();
A aEntity = new A();
bEntity.setbEntity(aEntity);

this.entityManager.persist(A);
this.entityManager.persist(B);
this.entityManager.flush();
```

If you need to keep working with those entities on the same transaction, calling `entityManager.refresh` on a entity will make sure that all properties are in sync.

Comment: Hello, I've tried this just now. When I flush, b's A entity is hydrated but b's bId does not grab the id from A. So it fails

Comment: Ok, didn't fully understand the issue. After the flush, while still n the same transaction you may need to call `entityManager.refresh` on your entity to hydrate them with the inserted values.

Comment: Hmm, the error occurs during flush so I can't call entityManager.refresh after flush. The issue is I'm trying to create A and B in the same transaction but B's primary id relies on A's primary id. Although after persisting, B does contain A's entity (including id), somehow jpa does not know to hydrate B's id to be A's id. So at the point of flushing, B's id is 0